# Nothing shown on login screen after upgrade

Tags: 18.04

I just upgraded the ubuntu 18.04 few days ago.  After it is upgraded and rebooted, the screen shows nothing as [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbDjQ.png).  Try to run in safe mode and fix broken dpkg and restart is fine, but problem happens again after reboot once more.